# Assign citation style after the \usepackage{biblatex} in preamble

Tags: biblatex, package-options

Is it possible to assign the citation style with a command? (such as `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{...}`)

I'm getting all `\usepackage{...}` in one file and settings in another. But I can not do:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{style=numeric-comp}
```

Because it gives the following error:

```
! Package keyval Error: style undefined.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{K1, author={A 1}, title={T 1}}
    @misc{K2, author={A 2}, title={T 2}}
    @misc{K3, author={A 3}, title={T 3}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    backend = biber,
    %style = numeric-comp,   <---   this fails!
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{K1, K2, K3}.
\printbibliography%
\end{document}
```

Using `\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}` works perfectly, but I would like to set the style in another file (in the preamble). I can not find how, or at least confirm that it is not possible.

I've also tried with `citestyle=numeric-comp` and gives the same result.

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE**

The idea is to separate into multiple files all the preamble of the document, because this is long (it's for my graduation thesis). And I have distributed this way (they are more files):

**File: Settings/Packages.tex**

```
%[...more packages...]
\usepackage{biblatex}   % space for a brief description
%[...more packages...]
```

**File: Settings/Config.tex**

```
%[...more configs...]
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    backend = biber,
    sortcites = true,
}
%[...more configs...]
```

**File: Main.tex**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\input{Settings/Packages}
\input{Settings/Config}
%[...more inputs...]
\loadglsentries{Glossary.tex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
%[...more chapters...]
\end{document}
```

So I need to apply the `style` after the `\usepackage`, because many of the other packages are made this way (koma-script, glossaries, amsmath, graphicx, PGF-TikZ, siunitx, hyperref, etc.).

Comment: You can pass the options in the `\documentclass` line (as long as two packages don't have the same option names, so not always possible.) Or you could use `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{<package>}`.

Comment: Thanks @christian-hupfer. @alan-munn I unknown the command `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}` (thanks) the problem is that I change the order of the rest of the document, so I put "after the \usepackage{biblatex}" (I update my question).

Comment: @Schcriher For the `biblatex` options listed it is *not* possible to do this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are planning to do is a good idea, since it's much easier to see what's going on if the options are listed with the package, but if you really want to do this, you have two options. (Pun intended).

1. Pass all options as global options to the `\documentclass`

By default, global options (i.e., those given in the `\documentclass` command) will be available to any package loaded, so as long as there aren't conflicting package options, you could pass your `biblatex` options (or any other options) as global options. This won't work for all package options.

2. Use `\PassOptionsToPackage`

For a more finegrained approach, you can use the `\PassOptionsToPackage` command *before* you load the package.

Here's an example of this technique. In this example, I deliberately used the `backend=bibtex` option because it it not the default in `biblatex`.  In your sample code, it only appeared that that option was working.

You can also see the effects of the placement of the command.  If you load `biblatex` first and then execute `\PassOptionsToPackage` the `backend` option will not work correctly. (Make sure you delete all your `.aux` files between each run as you test.)

```
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex

\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{K1, author={A 1}, title={T 1}}
    @misc{K2, author={A 2}, title={T 2}}
    @misc{K3, author={A 3}, title={T 3}}
\end{filecontents}
\PassOptionsToPackage{style=numeric-comp,backend=bibtex}{biblatex}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{K1, K2, K3}.
\printbibliography%
\end{document}
```

Specifically for the `biblatex` options it is *not* possible to load them after you load the package.  Section 3.1.1 of the `biblatex` documentation lists the following options that *must* be loaded at package loading time (i.e., with the `\usepackage` command or passed as described above):

- `backend`
- `style`, `bibstyle`, `citestyle`
- `natbib`
- `mcite`

So for these options there is no way to load the package and then set the option.

Comment: The reason for separating the inclusions and settings is the extension of the same. Not all options can be global (I remember reading in some packages this restriction). Yes, biber option works for me perfectly. I tried putting "before" and "after" `usepackage` and only works by putting it before (for `style` and `backend`). I will update my question to show the structure I'm doing. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Thank you very much @alan-munn, Yes. the manual is somewhat inaccurate to say `The following options must be used as Biblatex is loaded, i. e., in the optional argument to \usepackage`, even says `This means that you can't set the backend with, for example, \ExecuteBibliographyOptions in the preamble.` and to me it worked (although I think I'll put it next to `usepackage` to avoid strange errors).

Comment: @Schcriher No, the manual is not inaccurate. It only *appeared* that you were setting the `backend` option in your example code. It wasn't actually working, but appeared to work because you used `biber` which is the default.

Comment: With "inaccurate" I meant the first part gives the example put options in the `usepackage`, it sounds like a "possibility" but is _required_ to do so (or the shortcut `PassOptionsToPackage`). I may sound like me in that way, since English is not my native language. What the `backend` if possible I worked for it.

Comment: @Schcriher I'm a bit confused. The part of the manual you quote is quite explicit that the `backend` option can only be passed at package loading time, and this is in fact correct.

Comment: I was referring to `The following options must be used as Biblatex is loaded, i. e., in the optional argument to \usepackage`. But definitely "style" can not be set after the "usepackage".

Comment: I inadvertently came across this post today and you are right it clearly says `**must be** used as Biblatex is loaded` 

Comment: @Schcriher Better late than never! :)